# Why code analysis "is OK with" initialising a class variable but not reading that variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, variables

I am quite new to python and working on a test:

```
class MyTest(MyParentTest):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(MyTest, cls).setUpClass()

        cls.ipg_model = ngty.data_model.DataModel(
            ...
        )
        ipg_object = cls.ipg_model.create(ngty)
```

From above, the IDE allows me to do `cls.ipg_model =` but when I try `cls.ipg_model.create(` then it says "unresolved attribute reference 'ipg_model' for class 'RestClassTest'"

The IDE suggests to declare the variable outside of the methods (and that's how python teaches class variables) - and that'll probably work but I feel like I could learn something interesting about how python works :)

Comment: That's an IDE warning, not a Python error.

Comment: @Barmar yes :) But I think it's so simple that the background parser is about as smart as the compiler, in this case... - I sure didn't outsmart the team at Inteli-J with that one :D

Comment: Class variables are not resolved by the compiler in Python. It doesn't matter how smart the compiler is, because this isn't the compiler's job.

Comment: "the background parser is about as smart as the compiler" That's a big assumption.

Comment: Solving every possible case of "does this variable exist on this object" is equivalent to the halting problem (see [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)), so IDEs take the most common use cases into consideration. And "dynamically setting a slot on the `cls` class method object then accessing it" is evidently just not seen as a common enough use case to care about doing a control-flow analysis for.

Comment: Static analysis of dynamic languages like Python is difficult. IDEs make use of some heuristics.

Comment: very interesting. I am a Java dude (actually helped develop Java-based IDEs for COBOL) and I am used to a strongly typed, compiled, language, where the parser can be as strong as the compiler, if not more clever at understanding the code structure

Comment: And in Java could you add new attributes on the fly like that? I don't program in Java, but I think you have to declare all the variables up front.

Comment: @Barmar not in the Java versions I worked with (who knows what heresy was recently added to claw back some coolness)... But Python allows some things that Java doesn't, already, so I thought that could work :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the difference. Python is a very dynamic language, which means you basically have to run the code to reason about it. Java is static, so for instance the type of a local variable is known to a compiler (or a sufficiently advanced IDE).